# ¿Por qué se ejecuta el código correctamente solo una vez?

Tags: java, while

(ejercicio sala de cine). La primera vez selecciono una posición 1 array(0,0), la cual no se
puede usar porque esta marcada con cero según el ejercicio los asientos marcados con cero no se
pueden usar, el programa funciona correctamente y se despliega el mensaje "asiento restringido",
las siguientes ocasiones que selecciono un asiento marcado con cero, ya no lo detecta.

```java
do {
    System.out.println("Elija número de butaca: ");
    ButacaAsignada = Entrada.nextInt();
    Aux = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            if (Sala[i][j] == ButacaAsignada) {
                Posicion = Aux; fila = i;  columna = j;
            } Aux++;
        }
    }
    if (Posicion >= 1) {
        Sala[fila][columna] = 99;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Butaca restringida");
    }
    Contador++;
} while (Contador <= Compra);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        System.out.print("[" + Sala[i][j] + "]" + "  ");
    }
}
```

[image: Descripción del error]

Answer (score 3):

No funciona desde un principio aunque tal y como está montado parezca que sí. Al final está la solución:

Cuando pides la butaca 1 no la encuentra porque `Sala[0][0]` vale `0` y utiliza el valor por defecto de Posición, que no es mayor ni igual que `1`, por lo que te da el error.

El código hace esto:

```java
i = 0
j = 0
Aux = 1
ButacaAsignada = 1
Sala[0][0] == 0
Sala[0][0] != ButacaAsignada
```

Como no hay ningún elemento en Sala que valga 1 el if no se ejecuta:

```java
if (Sala[i][j] == ButacaAsignada) {
    Posicion = Aux; fila = i;  columna = j;
}
Aux++;
```

Entonces las varibles quedan así:

```java
Posicion = 0
fila = 0
columna = 0
```

Y en este if, como `Posicion` es `0` ejecuta el else dando el mensaje de Butaca Restringida.

```java
if (Posicion >= 1) {
    Sala[fila][columna] = 99;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Butaca restringida"); 
}
```

La segunda vez cuando pides la butaca 5 tampoco la encuentra porque `Sala[0][4]` también vale `0`. El código hace esto cuando llega a la 5ª posición:

```java
i = 0
j = 4
Aux = 5
ButacaAsignada = 5
Sala[0][4] == 0
Sala[0][4] != ButacaAsignada
```

El resto queda igual.

Cuando pides la butaca 2 la encuentra y le da a `Posición` el valor de `2` y a `Sala[0][1]` el valor `99`.

```java
i = 0
j = 1
Aux = 2
ButacaAsignada = 2
Sala[0][1] == 2
Sala[0][0] == ButacaAsignada
```

Entonces el if se ejecuta:

```java
if (Sala[i][j] == ButacaAsignada) {
    Posicion = Aux; fila = i;  columna = j;
}
Aux++;
```

Entonces las variables quedan así:

```java
Posicion = 2
fila = 0
columna = 1
Sala[0][1] = 99
```

Cuando pides dos entradas y vuelves a pedir la butaca `1` no la encuentra de nuevo:

```java
i = 0
j = 0
Aux = 1
ButacaAsignada = 1
Sala[0][0] == 0
Sala[0][0] != ButacaAsignada
```

Igual que al principio como no hay ningún elemento en Sala que valga 1 el if no se ejecuta:

```java
if (Sala[i][j] == ButacaAsignada) {
    Posicion = Aux; fila = i;  columna = j;
}
Aux++;
```

Pero resulta que `Posición` sigue valiendo `2` desde el ciclo anterior, por lo que vuelve a asignar un `99` a la segunda butaca sin dar error porque la única validación que haces es si el valor de Sala es mayor o igual a 1.

```java
Posicion = 2
fila = 0
columna = 1
Sala[0][1] = 99
```

Te recomiendo que `Posición` la reinicies a `0` en cada bucle y que en el if compares `Aux`, que es la que te da la posición en lugar del valor de `Sala` y puedes ver en los ejemplos de arriba que su valor coincide con el que estás buscando:

```java
do {
    System.out.println("Elija número de butaca: ");
    ButacaAsignada = Entrada.nextInt();
    Aux = 1;

    Posicion = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {

            if (Aux == ButacaAsignada) {

                Posicion = Aux; fila = i;  columna = j;
            } Aux++;
        }
    }

    if (Posicion>= 1  && Sala[fila][columna]>=1) {

        Sala[fila][columna] = 99;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Butaca restringida");
    }
    Contador++;
} while (Contador <= Compra);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        System.out.print("[" + Sala[i][j] + "]" + "  ");
    }
}
```

Un saludo

Comment: La respuesta con la explicación dada y algo de código sería de mayor utilidad.

Comment: Hola @Iván Uría, gracias por comentar, si funciona, si ves la imagen que compartí , se aprecia como funciona el  código https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrOVi.png

Comment: Dame unos minutos que hago caso a @Bicho. Parece que funciona, pero no. No te quedes solo con la primera frase.

Comment: Editado. A veces las cosas parecen que funcionan, pero es que solo no hemos tenido en cuenta que un fallo puede hacer parecer que funciona.